# SQL Insert Date Mystery on 2012 from 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have migrated a 2005 db to 2012

There is a stored procedure that run to insert todays date into a table

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblTime WHERE [Day] = DATEPART(day,GETDATE())
                                    AND [Month] = DATEPART(month,GETDATE())
                                    AND [Year]= DATEPART(year,GETDATE()) )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblTime (Period,[Day],[Month],[Year],MonthPrefix)
        VALUES (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105),
                DATEPART(day,GETDATE()),
                DATEPART(month,GETDATE()),
                DATEPART(year,GETDATE()),
                CASE DATEPART(month,GETDATE()) 
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'JAN'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'FEB'
                    WHEN 3 THEN 'MAR'
                    WHEN 4 THEN 'APR'
                    WHEN 5 THEN 'MAY'
                    WHEN 6 THEN 'JUN'
                    WHEN 7 THEN 'JUL'
                    WHEN 8 THEN 'AUG'
                    WHEN 9 THEN 'SEP'
                    WHEN 10 THEN 'OCT'
                    WHEN 11 THEN 'NOV'
                    WHEN 12 THEN 'DEC'
                    END
                )
END
```

When this is run on the new 2012 SQL box the date gets put in as

2015-12-06 00:00:00

But the same SP on the old 2005 would read

2015-06-12 00:00:00

I have checked that the 2 servers have the same language settings etc.

But is there something I have missed.

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you check the default language and collation on the server/database? When you select the date using the same convert style do you get different results?

Comment: This isn't  a SQL Server problem - you are using the wrong type. Even in 2005 you should *not* pass or store dates as strings because any locale or language change will lead to problems. In 2012 you can use the `date` type if you don't want the time part.

Comment: Are you trying to strip the time part? 105 is the Italian `dd-mm-yyyy` format. What is the field's type and what is the query that you expect to return an ISO date? If `period` is a `datetime` you are forcing a needless (and faulty) conversion from one locale to another. Use `cast(GETDATE() as date)`

Comment: You really should redesign your table.  
Right now you are keeping a single date in 5 different columns, 2 of them are char or varchar.  
Instead, you should simply keep a date column, and handle the display format either in select statements or on the presentation layer (the later being the best option). 

Since you are switching from 2005 to 2012, I understand that it's a table that contains values and you have probably already built your applications that uses the data in that table, so this might be a painfull process. However, it's the best advice I can give you.

Comment: You can also get rid of the month name lookup by using `FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMM','en-US')`

Comment: @ZoharPeled the OP may be trying to fill a Date auxiliary table, where the date is the key and the years, quarters, names etc are added as extra fields to facilitate grouping, filtering and reporting

Comment: Thanks for this,  I have checked the 2 server and there were different.  After changing the values to match and re-running the SP the results were still same!

Comment: @KevinRedfern do you *really* want the Italian format? What are you trying to do? What is the type of `Period`? If you want to store today's date, just do `cast(GETDATE() as date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

on the two different SQL box and chek the dateformat.
To set that value use

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
```

or any other combination like mdy, dmy, etc

Comment: Passing dates as strings is a bad idea in general, but at least in SQL Server 2012 you can use `PARSE` or `TRY_PARSE` instead of changing options

Comment: Thanks for this, I have checked the 2 server and there were different. After changing the values to match and re-running the SP the results were still same!

Answer (score 0):

I have got to change the language for each user.

There were set to English, but should of been British English for my instance.

Once changed, restarted the instance.

Thanks for the above post for pointing me in the correct direction.